# How to select First item in FlatList as default one?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-native-flatlist

I'm trying to use Flatlist like Sidebar, but it intializes only after clicking on it,
Is there any way by which I can make first flatlist item as default one.
In other words onclick work should happen before page load like in lifecycleHooks
Also suggest me If there is any way to create sidebar dynamically instead of using Flatlist

```
<FlatList
  data={Object.keys(this.state.groups)}
  renderItem ={({ item, index }) => 
  (
    <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={() => { this.showDetails(item),this.setState({itemIndex:index}) }}
      // onPress={() => alert(item)}
    >
    {console.log(index,"index of cards",Object.keys(this.state.groups),"item index")}  
    <View style={{width: 280, height:54 , flexDirection:"row",alignItems:"center",backgroundColor: (this.state.itemIndex === index) ? "#74C947" : "#F6F6F6"}}>
    {/* Use ExcludeIcon.svg  for stop symbol*/}
    {(this.state.itemIndex === index) ? 
    <Image source={require("../../../assets/images/WhiteTick.svg")} style={{width:16,height:11,marginLeft:15,marginRight:9}}/>            
    : 
    <Image source={require("../../../assets/images/GreenTick.svg")} style={{width:16,height:11,marginLeft:15,marginRight:9}}/>
    } 
    <Text style={{
      fontStyle:"normal",
      fontWeight:"500",
      fontSize: 16,              
      color: (this.state.itemIndex === index) ? "#FFFFFF" : "#333333",
      textTransform:"capitalize"
    }}>
      {item}
    </Text>
    </View>
  </TouchableOpacity>
  )
}
  keyExtractor={item => item}
 />
```

[image: Before On click]

[image: After On Click]

Comment: Initialize your state with default value like `state = { itemIndex: 0 };` I have answered as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way

```
 state = {
   itemIndex: 0
 };

componentDidMount(){
  this.showDetails(this.state.itemIndex);
}
```

Comment: I have already used this only but First element is not displaying. It displays only after Onclick. Only my CSS changes are happening

Comment: @KimiRaikkonen9790 you have to call `showDetails` for first item explicitly so I have updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can keep default value of itemIndex to 0 which selects the first element.

```js
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {itemIndex : 0};
  }
```

Comment: I have already used this only but First element is not displaying. It displays only after Onclick.